# Moq Verify says method was never called, but it was

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I have the following code which reads a Transaction from Kafka, and updates the account balance to show that transaction

```
public class KafkaConsumerService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IConsumer<string, Transaction> _kafkaConsumer;
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly ICalculator _calculator;

    public KafkaConsumerService(
        IConsumer<string, Transaction> kafkaConsumer,
        IRepository repository,
        ICalculator calculator
    )
    {
        _kafkaConsumer = kafkaConsumer;
        _repository = repository;
        _calculator = calculator;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var consumeResult = await Task.Run(() => _kafkaConsumer.Consume(stoppingToken), stoppingToken);
        var transaction = consumeResult.Message.Value;

        var account = await _repository.GetAccount(transaction.Account);
        await _repository.UpdateAccount(_calculator.CalculateAccount(account, Normalize(transaction)));
    }

    private Transaction Normalize(Transaction transaction)
    {
        if (!transaction.IsCancellation)
        {
            return transaction;
        }

        return new Transaction(transaction)
        {
            Amount = transaction.Amount * -1,
            IsCancellation = false
        };
    }
}
```

I have then written the following unit test for this, using XUnit and Moq

```
public class KafkaConsumerServiceTest
{
    private readonly Mock<IConsumer<string, Transaction>> _kafka = new();
    private readonly Mock<IRepository> _repository = new();
    private readonly Mock<ICalculator> _calculator = new();

    private readonly Fixture _fixture = new();
    private readonly KafkaConsumerService _kafkaConsumerService;

    public KafkaConsumerServiceTest()
    {
        _kafkaConsumerService = new KafkaConsumerService(_kafka.Object, _repository.Object, _calculator.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task KafkaConsumerService_ProcessesCancelationTransaction()
    {
        _fixture.Customize<Transaction>(composer => composer
            .With(transaction => transaction.IsCancellation, true)
        );

        var transaction = _fixture.Create<Transaction>();
        _kafka
            .Setup(consumer => consumer.Consume(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .Returns(new ConsumeResult<string, Transaction>
            {
                Message = new Message<string, Transaction>
                {
                    Value = transaction,
                },
            });

        var result = _fixture.Create<Account>() with
        {
            AccountName = transaction.Account
        };

        _repository
            .Setup(repository => repository.GetAccount(transaction.Account))
            .ReturnsAsync(result);

        _calculator
            .Setup(calculator => calculator.CalculateAccount(It.IsAny<Account?>(), It.IsAny<Transaction>()))
            .Returns(result);

        await _kafkaConsumerService.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);

        _repository.Verify(repository =>
            repository.GetAccount(transaction.Account)
        );
        _calculator.Verify(calculator =>
            calculator.CalculateAccount(result, transaction)
        );
        _repository.Verify(repository => repository.UpdateAccount(result));
    }
}
```

However I then get the following error

```
Moq.MockException

Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: repository => repository.GetAccount("Account73ccea18-e39c-493f-9533-7af7f983b8ab")

Performed invocations:

   Mock<IRepository:1> (repository):

      IRepository.GetAccount("Account73ccea18-e39c-493f-9533-7af7f983b8ab")
      IRepository.UpdateAccount(Account { AccountName = Account73ccea18-e39c-493f-9533-7af7f983b8ab, Amount = 119 })
```

As you can see it says the method `GetAccount("Account73ccea18-e39c-493f-9533-7af7f983b8ab")` was never called, however right below it under Performed invocations, it says it was called.

If anyone has any ideas as to what is going wrong here I would appreciate it.

**EDIT**
Adding an await Task.Delay(100) on the unit tests seem to fix the problem, however this isnt an ideal solution, and I still dont understand why the issue occurs in the first place.

**EDIT #2**
It seems that removing the extension of BackgroundService (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) seems to fix the test aswell. Could this somehow be causing a race condition in my code?

Comment: Where's the method `StartAsync()` defined? You're only showing `ExecuteAsync()`, but you're calling `await _kafkaConsumerService.StartAsync()` in your test. What's happening there?

Comment: My class is extending Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.BackgroundService which includes the StartAsync method. Esentially its just a method which calls the abstract task ExecuteAsync which I override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into this further. It appears that `BackgroundService.StartAsync` will call `ExecuteAsync`, and then `return Task.CompletedTask`

```cs
public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     // Store the task we're executing
    _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

    // If the task is completed then return it,
    // this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
    if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        return _executingTask;
    }

    // Otherwise it's running
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This then meant that my code has not finished executing yet, hence why my moq assertions failed. I then assume that the timing between these two was very close, so that by the time the error was generated, the methods had been called hence the confusing error message.

I fixed this issue by simply waiting for the executed task to be completed

```
await _kafkaConsumerService.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
await _kafkaConsumerService.ExecuteTask;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit could be this:

```cs
return new Transaction(transaction)
{
    Amount = transaction.Amount * -1,
    IsCancellation = false
};
```

When you verify against an instance, it is doing a reference check so it cannot be a different newly made object.

Try

```cs
_repository.Verify(repository =>
    repository.GetAccount(It.IsAny<string>())
);
_repository.Verify(repository => repository.UpdateAccount(It.IsAny<Transaction>()));
```

You may also use `It.Is<Transaction>(t => t.AccountName == "account")` to validate specific values in the assertion.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunatly It.IsAny<string> doesnt work either.

I also dont think this is the issue since the error happens before we call this normalize method. and removing the normalize all together doesnt fix it either.

Ive also noticed that adding an await Task.Delay(100) in the unit test fixes the issue. But thats not ideal. Could there be some sort of race condition going on here?

Comment: @JDChris100 Please add that additional information to the question.

Comment: Try rewriting `Task.Run(() => _kafkaConsumer.Consume(stoppingToken), stoppingToken)`. Not sure why it needs to be in a separate Task.

Comment: @beautifulcoder That's probably because `Consume()` is a long-running blocking call.

Comment: Yep, Consume is a Kafka method that will block the thread until a message is available to consume, so I had to write it in a Task.Run so it doesnt block the thread